# Base class of struct construct in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4(v=VS.71).aspx

As per the above link…..  “Structs, however, inherit from the base class Object……”

As per the below link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx
Struct is implemented after ValueType in the hierarchy.

“struct” is derived from which class? Or compiler treats “struct” reserve word to make any declaration using “struct” as value type?
Missing the small thread in overall understanding.
Thank you for your help.
Smith

Comment: What is it that you aren't understanding? is this an Interview Question...? sounds like one..LOL

Comment: struct -> ValueType -> Object

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The hierarchies (skipping any class subtypes) are:

1. `struct .. -> ValueType -> Object`
2. `class .. -> Object`

Demo:

```
struct S {}
class C {}

// or see `is` as per Jeff Mercado's comment
typeof(ValueType).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(S)); // True
typeof(object).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(S));    // True

typeof(ValueType).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(C)); // False
typeof(object).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(C));    // True
```

Comment: It would be easier to use `is`.  ;)

Comment: from where int and bool, all these primitive data types come from? Why the syntax defination of int does not shows the inheritance hierarchy?http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: @LaysomeSmith `int` is an alias for [`struct System.Int32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx); the other keyword-types are also just aliases in C#. (This differs from Java where `int` and the other primitive-types are special-cased directly.)

Comment: OK. I got this alias part.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx
In the above definition there is no documentation of inheritance hierarchy for system.int32?
All the types are derived from object class in c#. Why the inheritance hierarchy is missing here.
Thank you,
Smith

Comment: System.Int32 *is a* structure as per the documentation linked. Structures, System.Int32 or otherwise, *cannot* extend any types and have the fixed hierarchy shown above (they may implement interfaces, but this does not change the hierarchy). I suspect this is discussed in better detail in the CLS. The inheritance is not "missing" so much as a detail left to be discussed elsewhere -- e.g. how does one know that all classes have `object` as the hierarchy root when it is not listed as a base in the documentation? :)

Comment: A `struct` may behave as an `object` most of the time, but it is not inherited from `object`.

You can see this with covariant type definitions. You can assign a `Func<string>` to a `Func<object>` because the type parameter is covariant and `string` inherits from `object`. But you cannot assign a `Func<int>` to a `Func<object>`, which implies that `int` does *not* inherit from `object`.

I suspect this is similar to how you can do `null` checks on `Nullable<T>` instances even though `Nullable<T>` is a value type; the compiler tries really hard to give you a fake reality.

Comment: @meustrus I guess we have to use dynamic as replacement for a basetype though.