# What is int in c#?

Tags: c#, value-type, reference-type

What is `int` in C#? Is it a keyword, or is it a class derived from *system.ValueTypes*?  If it is a keyword then how do the following lines compile

```
int i = new int(); // If int is not a class then how does it have a default constructor

Console.WriteLine(i.ToString()); // If int is not a class then how does it have member functions
```

If `int` is a class then why is it not necessary to always initialize it with `new`? How does the following line compile?

```
int i = 8;
```

Comment: Who says "structs" or "value-types" *can't* have Methods? That's some Java nonsense talking :) `int` is `System.Int32` which is a `struct`-type. (To make life simpler the compiler knows about various "literal" constructs like integers, floating point values, and strings. However, it's a fixed set. E.g. there is no "literal" for a GUID, so `new Guid(string)` is required.)

Comment: All value types can have methods, Java is the silly exception.

Comment: `int i = 8` compiles for the same reason that `string foo = "bar"` compiles.  `8` is a literal of the type `int`, just like `"bar"` is a literal of the type `string`.

Comment: Well if int is an alias for a _struct_ `System.Int32`, then how does it inherit from the `System.Object` class??

Comment: @user1232138 Every `struct` is a sub-type of `ValueType` and `ValueType` is a sub-type of `object`. Unlike a `class` other sub-types cannot be specified with a `struct` (although interfaces can be specified). This is how the Type tree is defined in C#/CLR. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461789/base-class-of-struct-construct-in-c-sharp Of course, this isn't the entire story. `object x = 1` "boxes" (keyword) the `int` value, for instance.

Comment: But in C#, structures cannot inherit from other structures or classes then how does `int` inherit from `System.Object`..

Comment: @user1232138 They can. And they do. But they have a *fixed* hierarchy. That is, there is a default: `struct -> (abstract class) System.ValueType -> (class) System.Object` which *cannot* be changed, just as one cannot make a class *not* ultimately derived from `object`. Every `struct` value *is a* `ValueType`. Every `ValueType` *is a* `object`. Thus every `struct` value *is a* `object`.

Comment: (Oops, I meant: "`ValueType`, an abstract class, *is a* sub-type of `object`.")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *int* is an *alias* of CTS type `System.Int32` [structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcx1eb1e.aspx#Structures).

Read SO answer posted by Eric Lippert - [How do ValueTypes derive from Object (ReferenceType) and still be ValueTypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1682604/142822)

Comment: Well if int is an alias for a _struct_ `System.Int32`, then how does it inherit from the `System.Object` class??

Answer (score 3):

`int` is a keyword that is an alias for the value type (`struct`) `System.Int32`.

Being a regular value type, I believe its inheritance is `System.Object` -> `System.ValueType` -> `System.Int32`.

Because `int` has a literal notation, like strings and other number types, you can create instances of it without `new`.

Comment: If int is an alias for a _struct_ `System.Int32`, then how does it inherit from the `System.Object` class??

Comment: @user1232138: *All* value types have `System.Object` as an indirect base class.

Answer (score 0):

To explain code with code:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(int) == typeof(Int32)); // Outputs: True
Console.WriteLine(typeof(int).Name); // Outputs: Int32
```